# Unifying function exits with LLVM

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Let's say I have this function in C/C++:

```
int foo(int x) {

    if (x <= 1) return 1;
    return x * foo(x-1);
}
```

And I compile it with Clang.
Clang generates the following IR:

```
; Function Attrs: ssp uwtable
define i32 @_Z3fooi(i32 %x) #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 %x, i32* %2, align 4
  %3 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %4 = icmp sle i32 %3, 1
  br i1 %4, label %5, label %6

; <label>:5                                       ; preds = %0
  store i32 1, i32* %1, align 4
  br label %12

; <label>:6                                       ; preds = %0
  %7 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %8 = load i32, i32* %2, align 4
  %9 = sub nsw i32 %8, 1
  %10 = call i32 @_Z3fooi(i32 %9)
  %11 = mul nsw i32 %7, %10
  store i32 %11, i32* %1, align 4
  br label %12

; <label>:12                                      ; preds = %6, %5
  %13 = load i32, i32* %1, align 4
  ret i32 %13
}
```

As you can see, LLVM passes optimizes out the code and creates a "return register" (where I put the return value), and a "return block" (where the return value is effectively returned).

I'm trying to get the same effect, but when I use SROA pass or the Instruction Combining pass, they translate the exits in a `phi` instruction:

```
; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @__HF3fooTi(i32 %x) #0 {
  %1 = icmp sle i32 %x, 1
  br i1 %1, label %2, label %3

; <label>:2                                       ; preds = %0
  br label %7

; <label>:3                                       ; preds = %0
  %4 = sub nsw i32 %x, 1
  %5 = call i32 @__HF3fooTi(i32 %4)
  %6 = mul nsw i32 %x, %5
  br label %7

; <label>:7                                       ; preds = %3, %2
  %.0 = phi i32 [ 1, %2 ], [ %6, %3 ]
  ret i32 %.0
}
```

My question is: which solution is faster? And which pass is Clang using to achieve this? (In the Clang source files I found the 2 passes I used, and they give me this different result)

Comment: Why don't you test it to see what is quickest?

Comment: I can't track the execution time for the second IR, and the 2 IRs are not identical